# Получаю ответ от сервера 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-status-code-400

Разрабатываю фул-стек приложение на Mongo, React, Express, Node.js.
Есть форма с полями "email" и "password" и кнопкой "Регистрация". При получение на сервере обо поля проходят валидацию на с помощью метода check (express-validator). При отправке формs ошибку 400. Застрял - все проверил, а ошибку найти не могу.
Консоль node.js выдает следующую информацию.

```
Line 34:19:  'data' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
[
[0]   {
[0]     value: undefined,
[0]     msg: 'Not correct email',
[0]     param: 'email',
[0]     location: 'body'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     value: undefined,
[0]     msg: 'Minimal password length is 6 symbols',
[0]     param: 'password',
[0]     location: 'body'
[0]   }
[0] ]
```

Ниже код:
Страница авторизации:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { useHttp } from "../hooks/http.hook";
    import { useMessage } from "../hooks/message.hook";
    import {useEffect} from 'react'
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
    
    export const AuthPage = ()=>{
        const auth = useContext(AuthContext)
        const message = useMessage()
        const {loading, request, error, clearError }=useHttp()
        const [form, setForm] = useState({
            email: '', password: ''
        })
    
        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('Error', error)
            message(error)
            clearError()
        }, [error, message, clearError])
        
        window.M.updateTextFields()
        useEffect(()=>{
    
        }, [])
        
        const changeHandler = event =>{
            setForm({...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
        }
        
        const registerHandler = async () =>{
            try{
                const data = await request ('api/auth/register', 'POST', {...form})
                console.log(data.message)
            } catch(e){}
        }
        
        const loginHandler = async () =>{
            try{
                const data = await request ('api/auth/login', 'POST', {...form})
             auth.login(data.token, data.userId)
            } catch(e){}
        }
    
        return(
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s6 offset-s3">
                    <h1>Сократи ссылку</h1>
                    <div className="card blue darken-1">
                        <div className="card-content white-text">
                            <span className="card-title">Авторизация</span>
                            <div>
    
                                <div className="input-field">
                                    <input placeholder="Введите email"
                                    id="email" 
                                    type="text"
                                    name="email"
                                    className="yellow-input"
                                    onChange={changeHandler}
                                    />
                                        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                                </div>
    
                                <div className="input-field">
                                    <input placeholder="Введите пароль"
                                    id="password" 
                                    type="password"
                                    name="password"
                                    className="yellow-input"
                                    onChange={changeHandler}
                                    />
                                        <label htmlFor="password">Пароль</label>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-action">
                            <button 
                            className="btn yellow darken-4"
                            style={{marginRight: 10}}
                            disabled={loading}
                            onClick={loginHandler}
                            >
                            Войти
                            </button>
                            <button 
                            className="btn grey lighten-1 black-text"
                            onClick={registerHandler}
                            disabled={loading}
                            >
                            Регистраиця
                            </button>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Роутер:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs') 
const config = require('config')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const User = require('../models/User')
const router = Router()

// /api/auth/register
router.post(
    '/register', [
        check('email', 'Not correct email').isEmail(),
        check('password', 'Minimal password length is 6 symbols')
        .isLength({ min: 6 })
    ],
    async(req, res) => {
        try {
         
            const errors = validationResult(req)
            
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    errors: errors.array(),
                    message: 'Not correct data during registration'
                })
            }

            const { email, password } = req.body
            
            const candidate = await User.findOne({ email })

            if (candidate) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Such User already exists' })
            }

            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12)

            const user = new User({ email, password: hashedPassword })

            await user.save()

            res.status(201).jason({ message: 'User created' })

        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something goes wrong, try once more' })
        }
    })
module.exports = router
```

Хук http

```
import {useState, useCallback} from 'react'
export const useHttp = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    const request = useCallback(async (url, method="GET", body=null, headers={}) =>{
        setLoading(true)
        try {
         
         if(body){
             body=JSON.stringify(body)
             Headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
         }
         const response=await fetch(url, {method, body, headers})
         
         const data = await response.json()

         if (!response.ok){
             throw new Error(data.message || "Something goes wrong")
         }
         setLoading(false)
         return data
        }catch(e){
            console.log('Catch', e.message)
            setLoading(false)
            setError(e.message)
            throw e
        }

    }, [])

    const clearError = useCallback(() => setError(null),[])
return {loading, request, error, clearError}
```

Comment: Ошибка "Not correct data during registration"

Comment: ну ок. ваш бекенд сам генерирует эту ошибку, значит вы можете посмотреть что служит причиной ошибки, в ответе сервера в консоли. и распечатать errors.array() на серверной стороне. в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Благодарю. Помогло подобраться чуть ближе к решению. С формы данные не считываются в этой части кода (приведу ниже). Переменная data не используется, поскольку в нее не передаются данные с формы. Пробовал через event.target.getAttribute('name') - безрезультатно

Comment: const changeHandler = event =>{
            setForm({...form, [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
        }
        
        const registerHandler = async () =>{
            try{
                const data = await request ('api/auth/register', 'POST', {...form})
                console.log(data.message)
            } catch(e){}
        }

Comment: ниже результат консоли ```[0]   {
[0]     value: undefined,
[0]     msg: 'Not correct email',
[0]     param: 'email',
[0]     location: 'body'
[0]   },
[0]   {
[0]     value: undefined,
[0]     msg: 'Minimal password length is 6 symbols',
[0]     param: 'password',
[0]     location: 'body'
[0]   }
[0] ] ```

Comment: Дима, добавляйте в вопрос, читать не возможно.

Comment: вопрос: у вас [эта](https://github.com/vladilenm/mern-full-course/blob/f917951b3a6042ac7ebf123ee392ac0251f443da/app.js#L8) строка прописана?

Comment: Извините за форматирование. Перенос строки через enter не переводит на новую сроку, а отправляет комментарий. Строка которую Вы указали прописана верно.